# automake subdir-objects is disabled

Tags: linux, gnu-make, automake

I'm getting the below error with automake. I know you can put AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects" at the top of Makefile.am. But how can I set this behaviour for all files, so I don't need to do it case by case?

```
Makefile.am:454: warning: source file 'libs/esl/src/esl_threadmutex.c' is in a subdirectory,
          Makefile.am:454: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am:454: warning: source file 'libs/esl/ivrd.c' is in a subdirectory,
          Makefile.am:454: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am:454: warning: source file 'libs/esl/src/esl_json.c' is in a subdirectory,
          Makefile.am:454: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am:454: warning: source file 'libs/esl/src/esl_buffer.c' is in a subdirectory,
          Makefile.am:454: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          tests/unit/unit.mk:6: warning: source file 'tests/unit/switch_event.c' is in a subdirectory,
          tests/unit/unit.mk:6: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am:854:   'tests/unit/unit.mk' included from here
          tests/unit/unit.mk:13: warning: source file 'tests/unit/switch_hash.c' is in a subdirectory,
          tests/unit/unit.mk:13: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am:854:   'tests/unit/unit.mk' included from here
          Makefile.am:441: warning: source file 'src/tone2wav.c' is in a subdirectory,
          Makefile.am:441: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
          Makefile.am: installing 'build/config/depcomp'
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not something you add "case-by-case", as `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS` applies to the whole project. It's also supposedly the only way it should be used in the future, thus the warnings; for now it's opt-in.

You can also set this in `configure.ac` with `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, see [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/automake/options.html) (full disclosure: I'm the author) for the full set of automake options you can use.

Comment: When I said case by case I meant per project not the individual files / folders. I'm looking for option that is universal in the automake config. Not updating each projects configue.ac. Thanks

Comment: Then there is none. There is no such thing as automake config.

Comment: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])` fails saying "configure.ac:11: error: option '[subdir-objects]' not recognized'.  Without square brackets it works.  This is automake (GNU automake) 1.16.3.